# Select Cell From SearchBar in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar, didselectrowatindexpath

I am trying to grab the information from cell supplied while searching and bring it back to prior view controller. Here is my code:

```
   //variables:
   var searching = false
   var cityArray = ["New York City, NY", "LA, CA"]
   var searchCity = [String()]
   
  //setup
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     if searching {
        return searchCity.count
    } else {
      return cityArray.count
 }
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CityTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! 
  CityTableViewCell 
  if searching {
   cell.cityLabel.text = searchCity[indexPath.row]
  } else {
  cell.cityLabel.text = cityArray[indexPath.row]
  } 
  return cell 
 }



    //tells what do once selecting the tableviewcell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if searching {
     //This is the problem. I am telling to take the search city IndexPath.row
     currentCity = searchCity[indexPath.row]
    } else {
     currentCity = cityArray[indexPath.row]
   }  
    //currentCity is then used to go back to prev. VC and tell it what city was selected
   if let presentingVC = presentingViewController as? DealsViewController {
        if presentingVC.city != self.currentCity {
            presentingVC.city = self.currentCity
            presentingVC.deleteAllDeals()
            presentingVC.noDeals = false
            presentingVC.cityOutlet.setTitle(self.currentCity,for: .normal)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                presentingVC.getDealInfo {
                presentingVC.DealsTableView.reloadData()
                presentingVC.DealsTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    searchBar.text = currentCity
    searching = false
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
 }

//searchBar

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchCity = cityArray.filter({$0.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText})
    searching = true
    reloadData()
}
```

Unfortunately, if it is in searching mode, the city returned does not change. It is the same as in previous view controller. I am looking to grab the exact indexpath.row from searchCity.

Thanks!

Comment: also is there a way to when searching make it both lowercase and uppercase sensitive:
for example "New York City, NY" vs. "new york city, ny" ... only the exact case will show up when searching?

Answer (score -1):

Figured this out:

1. There was a transcription error
2. to change it to lowercase:
   searchCity = cityArray.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) ==
   searchText.lowercased()})

Thanks!